# File and folder structure for JavaScript compiling with Webpack and Babel

Tags: webpack, babeljs, bootstrap-4

Not really sure if this issue is related to Webpack or Babel, but that is apparently what is used on CodePen to compile JavaScript.

I'm setting up a Bootstrap 4 project as a CodePen Project, but I'm having problems with the compiling of JavaScript files.

I know I have to include jQuery and Popover in my project to make the compiling process work. But I don't know where in my file/folder structure to place them.

I can see that all the JavaScript partials are referenced in the current folder like so:

```
import Alert from './alert'
```

While jQuery and Popper are referenced like so:

```
import $ from 'jquery'
```

I've tried to include jQuery, but removed it again, since it was failing. So where do I place it according to the "import" statements in the code samples above?

You can access my CodePen Project here: https://codepen.io/jeppeschaumburg/project/editor/fe6656b7d2fdd62fb50ec1cae8986b4a

Comment: There's no sign of JQuery in your folders

Comment: Yes, that's true. Notice that I wrote "I've tried to include jQuery, but removed it again, since it was failing." My question is where to put it – I was thinking that people knowledgeable about Webpack and/or Babel could answer me with the description and link provided.

Comment: If JQuery is a "jquery.js"  file that you out there manually then include it like the others, if you've grabbed it via npm then use the syntax you quoted

Comment: But then I would need to change the following code line in many files: "import $ from 'jquery'".

If I want to keep that code line and reference style where do I then place the jquery.js file? In a parent folder? In a sub folder?

Comment: You can still install jquery via npm  (`npm install --save jquery`) and import it like so : `import $ from "jquery"`

Comment: importing from `"./x"` is looking for a "local" script `x` where importing from `"x"` is looking for a "global" (npm imported or globals) script `x`

Comment: Okay. But I'm not using npm, I'm using CodePen. So I need to upload the JS file somewhere. But I think I got it now. I'll try to change the reference in all of my JS partials then.